Can I do "WITH INSERT do INSERT" in Drizzle?
I have two tables, users and settings. When a user account is created, I also want to create a row in the settings table which stores the user.id
The Drizzle docs mention you can do WITH subquery AS (SELECT ...) INSERT ... https://orm.drizzle.team/docs/update#with-update-clause
But I can't find documentation on using an INSERT as the subquery (i.e. WITH subquery AS (INSERT INTO users) INSERT INTO settings)
In Drizzle, I want to do something like:
const user = db.$with("user").as(
  db
    .insert(users)
    .values(...)
    .returning({ id: users.id})
);

await db.with(user)
    .insert(settings)
    .values({ settings.user_id: sql`(select id from ${user})`, ... })
    .returning({ id: settings.id});

Or in SQL:
WITH user AS (
  INSERT INTO users (...)
  VALUES (...)
  RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO settings (user_id, ...)
VALUES ((SELECT id FROM user), ...)
RETURNING id

Which would create rows in both tables with a single query
Does Drizzle support this?

WITH can only be used with SELECT queries -- it simply gives a name to the temporary table that results from that subquery.

The best solution I'm aware of turned out to be using a transaction, which allows me much of the benefits as if this were a single query:
await db.transaction(async (tx) => {
  const [user] = await tx.insert(users)...
  const [settings] = await tx.insert(settings).values({ user_id: user.id})
})

